# How can i use a global variable in IR llvm

Tags: llvm-ir

I want to insert an add instruction in LLVM IR format, something like `x = 0 ; ... x = x + 1`, where `x` is global variable. I have tried this:

```
Value *ZERO =  ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context),0);
GlobalVariable *gVar = new GlobalVariable(ZERO->getType(),false,GlobalValue::CommonLinkage,0,"x");
```

But I failed to use this variable later. How can I use this variable later?

Comment: Can you layout your code properly? Tnx

Comment: i want to count number of basic block , so i want to create counter (x), with initial value = 0 , and increment every basic block. so i try to create Value ZERO with zero value to initialize counter (x),

Comment: Are you trying to count INSIDE your IR, or in the code that generates the IR?

Comment: I try to count instruction inside IR , ( insert IR code that will be execute later, at run time ,(not static analysis, but dynamic) )